# Change of basis of the vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I understand that the change of basis of the matrix is 
$X' = U^{\dagger}XU$. But how about if I just want to change the basis of a vector $v$.

Is $v' = U^{\dagger}v$ the right one? Why does the $U$ disappear here?

Comment: You are using a lot of symbols without letting us know what any of them mean.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340978/change-of-basis-matrix

Comment: Presumably $U$ is unitary and $\dagger$ is the adjoint.

Comment: The key is to understand that $X'v'$ should produce the same result as $Xv$, but that output $Xv$ of $X$ should be expressed with respect to the new basis.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you. does that mean $v' = X'^{\dagger}Xv$?

Comment: It means that $Xv = UX'v'$, which is the same as $UX'(U^\dagger v)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  does this mean that $v' = U^{\dagger}v$ is correct? thanks.

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$